# How to push the data in XML view into the newly created JSON model?

Tags: sapui5

How to push the data in XML view into the newly created JSON model? I have created the comboBox and retrieved the data from JSON model and also created the text area when I select the item in combo box and insert data into the text area and submit a button both the data should be pushed to newly created JSON model in sapweb ide ui5

### page.view.xml:

```xml
<mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="pro.controller.Page" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
    <Page title="{i18n>title}">
        <content>
            <l:VerticalLayout>
                <ComboBox items="{ path: '/ProductCollection', sorter: { path: 'Name' } }">
                    <core:Item text="{Name}" /> </ComboBox>
                <TextArea value="" rows="8" />
                <Button type="Accept" text="Submit" press="onPress" /> </l:VerticalLayout>
        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

### page.controller.js

```js
sap.ui.define([
    'jquery.sap.global', 
    'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller', 
    'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";
    var PageController = Controller.extend("pro.controller.Page", {
        onInit: function() { 
            // set explored app's demo model on this sample 
            var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("pro", "/model/model.json"));
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
        }
    });
    return PageController;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

add a 'key' attribute to the combobox item. Also give the combobox and teaxarea some IDs.

```
<ComboBox id="selectBox" items="{ path: '/ProductCollection', sorter: { path: 'Name' } }">
                <core:Item key="{Naame}" text="{Name}" /> </ComboBox>
<TextArea id="textArea" value="" rows="8" />
```

On click of submit, get the selected values from the combobox and text area and push them into the model. I assume that you wanted to push this new data to the existing model and also your existing model is an array of objects.

```
sap.ui.define([
'jquery.sap.global',
'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
],function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) {
"use strict";
var PageController = Controller.extend("pro.controller.Page", {
  onInit: function() {
    var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("pro", "/model/model.json"));
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
  },
  onPress: function() {
    //get the value of the selected item in the combobox
    var selectedVal = this.getView().byId("selectBox").getSelectedKey();
    //get the textarea value
    var textAreaVal = this.getView().byId("textArea").getValue();
    this.getView().getModel().oData.push({
      key: selectedVal,
      value: textAreaVal
    });

  }
});
return PageController;
});
```

Comment: hi  i tried the code which you gave,but model is not getting updated,on submitting button its showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelectedKey' of undefined

Comment: can anyone tell how to push data to new json model every time data should be pushed to model

Comment: hi sarath ,can u please explain me how to merge two json models and how to push the input data to json model in sapui5

Comment: <mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="pro.controller.Page" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" ><Page title="{i18n>title}"><content><l:VerticalLayout><ComboBox id ="comboBox1"  items="{path: '/ProductCollection',sorter: { path: 'Name' }}"><core:Item key="{key}" text="{Name}" /></ComboBox><TextArea id="textArea" value="" rows="8" /><Button id="btn1" type="Accept" text="Submit" press="onPress"  />  </l:VerticalLayout>

Comment: <Table id="idFt" items="{path:'/tableData'}"> <items><ColumnListItem><cells><Text text="{val1}" /><Text text="{val2}" /></cells></ColumnListItem></items><columns><Column><Text text="Val1" /></Column><Column><Text text="Val2" /></Column></columns></Table></content></Page></mvc:View>

Comment: controller
sap.ui.define(["jquery.sap.global","sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller","sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) {var sValue, list, data, oModel;var PageController = Controller.extend("pro.controller.Page", {
onInit:function({oModel=newJSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("pro", "/model/model.json"));
this.getView().setModel(oModel);},onPress: function() {
 var selectedVal=this.getView().byId("comboBox1").getSelectedKey();
   //get the textarea value 
var textAreaVal=this.getView().byId("textArea").getValue();

Comment: data = {"tableData": [{val1: selectedVal,val2: textAreaVal}];var dataModal = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data);this.getView().setModel(dataModal);data.tableData.push({val1: selectedVal,val2: textAreaVal});}

Comment: model.json

{
 "ProductCollection": [
  {
      "key": "Machine 123",
  "Name": "Machine 123"
  },
  
   {
       "key": "Machine 456",
  "Name": "Machine 456"
  },
  
   {
  "key":"Machine 790",
  "Name": "Machine 790"
  }
  ]
 }

Comment: Above mentioned is the cod e what i have tried,i need to push the data to new model which i created in controller,mean while i should merge the two json model in controller